# What is the algorithm behind photoshop palette knife effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects

I am trying to find the algorithm or even the general idea behind some of the effects used in Photoshop. Specifically, the **palette knife** effect that simplifies the colors of an image. For instance, the image bellow:

[image]

turns into something like this:

[image: p]

I want for each group of pixels that have similar color, to turn into a simple block of one or two colors (in real time) as happens in Photoshop. Any idea of a method to do this is appreciated.

Comment: This is a programming question not a graphic design one. Perhaps ask on [so]?

Comment: @Luciano you are right. I asked the question there.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. I see that it's closed there as too broad and it might get closed here as off-topic. You should try to improve the question on Stack Overflow so they can help you over there.